# Give values in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want know if this it´s right :

```
<script>

var id = "1";
var element = "car";

if (element + id == "car") {
    alert("ok");
}    

</script>
```

The problem for me it´s i don´t know if it´s possible write element+id , or by other side it´s bad , only that´s it

Comment: For what value of *right*?

Comment: Yes, you can write `element+id`, it concatenate the strings. But there is no way here it gives something else than `"car1"`.

Comment: element + id is valid in your code, it will evaluate to "car1"

Comment: you can write like that, but what do you want to do?

Comment: Probably, you will need a else part too, in order to have a better understanding of the code!!

Comment: Question unclear ? the people answer me must be stupids because these people no problem for understand me perfectly and answer but other put the questions unclear , ok incredible

Comment: The question **is** unclear.

Comment: Unclear and 5 people answer and understand me perfectly ? no man no , unclear you and others

Comment: element+id will give you "1car" as a string which is not equal to "car". Hence it will not enter if

Answer (score 1):

`+` can be used to concatenate two strings -

As your variables are strings, you can use `+` there

```
var id="1";
var element="car";
```

`elemant+id` will be equals to `car1`

Comment: `+` *can* be used to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. U can use it. it's not bad and completely true.

Answer (score 0):

For string `+` is used as concatenation.

`element+id`  returns `car1`  therefore you if statement will look like

```
if("car1" == "car") {  // always false
alert("Ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this it has basic explanation for declaring variables in java script [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Of Course, you can.`var` in javascript supports different data types. But the result of `element+id`
 would be concatenated string ie `car1`.